# Changing an array call based on a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to alter the array group I am filtering on based on a state set on click:

```
{this.state.data.filter(items => items.{this.state.filtergroup} === this.state.filter).map((data)
```

however the items.{this.state.filtergroup} obviously doesn't work. How might I be able to set up a filter like this?

Comment: Show the full data structure of your state please. You probably want `items[this.state.filtergroup]` if the `filtergroup` refers to a key on the `data` objects but its not totally clear from the code you've shared.

Comment: That was actually all that was needed, just had to remove the ".". Thanks!